# Looking for an architecture that supports streaming counting, sketching and large set intersections

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hbase

I wonder if the Stackoverflow community could help me by suggesting a technology (i.e. HBase, Raiku, Cassandra, etc.) that would solve my problem. I have a large dataset which we would like to **update and query in real-time** which is of the order of **10s of terabytes**. Our dataset is a pixel stream which contains a user ID and one or more features (usually around 10). The total possible **features number in the millions**.

We are imagining our data model would look like:

**FEATUREID_TO_USER_TABLE**:
Feature id -> {UserID Hash, UserID Hash, ...}

**FEATUREID_TO_COUNTER_TABLE**:
feature id -> { Hour of since epic -> HyperLogLog byte blob }

We would like to keep a sorted set of User IDs sorted by the hash of the User ID. We also like to keep at most ~200k for each FEATUREID_TO_USER_TABLE entry evicting old IDs if a new ID has a lower hash value.

We would like the store to support the following operations (not necessarily expressed in SQL):

```
select FeatureID, count(FeatureID) from FEATUREID_TO_USER_TABLE where UserID in 
(select UserID from FEATUREID_TO_USER_TABLE where FeatureID = 1234)
    group by FeatureID;
```

And

```
update FEATUREID_TO_COUNTER_TABLE set HyperLogLog = NewBinaryValue where FEATUREID_TO_COUNTER_TABLE.id = 567
```

We believe the easiest way to shard this data across machines is by User ID.

Thanks for any ideas,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is a great choice for persisting the data, but you'll want something else for processing it in real-time.  I recommend you check out [Storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm), as it gives you real-time streaming data processing with relative ease.  It's an open source framework that handles concurrency and parallelization for you.  It's written on the JVM, but has language bindings for a variety of non-JVM languages as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your whole description though so I am shooting in the dark a bit on context.

Is there any way to partition your data so you can query into a partition?  This helps alot with scalability and querying as you scale.  You typically don't want to query into toooo large a table so instead query into a partition.

ie. PlayOrm has partitioning capabilities on cassandra so you can query one partition.

While PlayOrm does also have join queries, it does not do subselects at this time but typically clients just do a first call into the nosql store and then aggregate results and do a second query and it is still very very fast(probably as fast as if you made one call as even cassandra would have to make two calls internally to the other servers anyways).

hmmm, the more I read your post, I am not sure you should write SQL there as you may be able to do everything by primary key but I am not 100% sure.  That SQL is confusing as it grabs all the user ids in the row it seems and then just counts them???? as it is the same table in both select and subselect?

As far as sharding your data, you don't need to do anything since cassandra does that automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I blundered my original SQL example a bit - I just corrected it. Basically I want to be able to do intersections of says "users who have FeatureID A" with the users of who have FeatureID B. The complicated part is I'd like to keep a sketched set of userIDs by some sort of hash AND I like to intersect a large number of features.